# background image is not fit into full screen. The height is cutting down

Tags: html, image, css

```
  body
        {
        background-image: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;

        }
```

bottom of the image is not fit into the screen. I have added background image in css body   tag. Width is perfect.But height is not fit into the screen. I saw many examples.but it is not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working.

```
body
{
    background-image: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:870px;
    background-image: url('../Media/bg3.jpg');
}

footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Now it fit the full screen.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are enough to fix and stretch a background image !

```
body{   
background:url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

JSFIDDLE : -[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/XZhbY/)

Comment: It works perfectly for me ! Post your other code too .. Maybe you override something somewhere !

Comment: try the link above and see the code ! its just a few lines !

Answer (score 1):

U may use following code

```
body
        {
        background-image: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        height:100%;
        }
```

Comment: nice answer .so i give a tick

Answer (score 0):

try  `background-size: cover`, it should fit screen

Comment: i tried.But height is not fit into the screen. Width is ok.

Comment: could you provide jsfiddle? it should be simple to create

Answer (score 0):

You can set following properties,

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUEMM/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
body {
    background: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

---

#### CSS

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUEMM/1/)**</kbd>

```
    background-image: url('../Media/bg3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: when added this code the top of the image is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Add your background image as

```
background: url(../images/your_image.jpg) fixed no-repeat center center;
background: url(../images/your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center; /* if you don't want it fixed */
```

for divs inside it use this for complete center

```
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

remove body tag css class
and add html class to do that 
this is the code

```
`html { 
 background: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

`

Comment: no it is not coming. My background image size is width:1366 height:768 ..Plz tell me wt are the other methods

Comment: http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code  refer this one here also height problem.

Comment: anyone plz give me the solution. Or give me the best tutorial to solve the problem

Comment: if is not working you can add this
html { 
  background: url('../Media/bg3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}